# Crystal Reports XI ReportSDKException ( divide by zero ) / html preview (happens on server, but not on my local dev environment)

Tags: exception, intellij-idea, crystal-reports, zero, divide

In Crystal Reports XI (11) **I am getting a ReportSDKException "/ by zero" (e.g. divide by zero ) sometime before/during we go to preview the report in html.**  This happening on the middle tier (java) on our test server.  **It fails for the tester, but it works for me on my local dev**elopment environment running from IntelliJ.  **Pointing to the test database** and using the same search criteria, **I still couldn't get it to fail for me**.

All other reports in that reports module application work, except for one report, using a recently modified *.rpt file (REPORT_IN_QUESTION.rpt).

**The things I did in the REPORT_IN_QUESTION.rpt** file was to **delete one database field** (card id) and **introduce another one** (personal id number), which also required me to **modify the layout so everything fit**.  In so doing, ***I also chose a different Page Setup (I can't recall which I used now)***.  Upon initially entering CR XI IDE it told me the printer setup was not valid, and that it would just use the default.   That's why I chose a different Page Setup, as I just mentioned.

**What fixed the problem was to NOT change the Page Setup / Printer Layout options at all.  The tester was able to run a version of REPORT_IN_QUESTION.rpt with no formatting introduced - only the introduction of the new database field.**

I then did a final version of REPORT_IN_QUESTION.rpt, again, NOT changing the Page Setup - but just squeezing the fields in tighter, to make it all fit, with whatever my "default" was.   This also worked for the Tester.

All that said, I'm **trying to understand what was the specific cause of all this**.  My best guess was the Page Setup / Layout I introduced initially was somehow unknown on the server/workstation - and that resulted in some value becoming zero, and during the calculations to preview in html (position things like the field, etc) that divide by zero happened.

Any how, hopefully this proves helpful to someone else.  **I'm still curious to know if anyone out there has experienced anything similar.**  I didn't do a complete search of google, but I did see divide by zeros being mentioned in relation to printing and drivers.

**As for the initial exception - here is what gets thrown in more detail:**

```
2014-05-06 13:45:08,510 DEBUG [TP-Processor1] (ReportsServlet.java:98) - Loading reports config file /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/[...]/WEB-INF/classes/reports_setup.properties
2014-05-06 13:45:08,513 DEBUG [TP-Processor1] (ReportsServlet.java:121) - Connecting with driver:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver User:dbconn to DB:jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL = TCP)(PORT = 1521)(HOST = [...])))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = [...])))
2014-05-06 13:45:08,534 DEBUG [TP-Processor1] (ReportsServlet.java:152) - Running report [RptFile:REPORT_IN_QUESTION.rpt][Name:REPORT_IN_QUESTION][Location:1][Module:[...]][Operator:[...]][Pass:[...]][System:[...]]
2014-05-06 13:45:08,548 DEBUG [TP-Processor1] (SessionDAOHibernate.java:126) - [Session] Commit : 3ms
2014-05-06 13:45:08,549 DEBUG [TP-Processor1] (ReportsServlet.java:175) - Authentication: true
2014-05-06 13:45:11,855 ERROR [TP-Processor1] (ReportsServlet.java:293) - Error generating report
**com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException: / by zero---- Error code:-2147467259 Error code name:failed
        at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.request(Unknown Source)**
        at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.x.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.q.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.do(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.if(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ClientDocument.open(Unknown Source)
        **at com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.ReportClientDocument.open(Unknown Source)
        at com.cbnco.idsys.common.reports.soap.ReportsServlet.doPost(ReportsServlet.java:183)**
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:283)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:767)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:697)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:889)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.eq.else(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.eq.else(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.eq.aY(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.C(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ae.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ae.if(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.if(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.C(Unknown Source)
        at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.c.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.b.v.if(Unknown Source)
        ... 26 more
Caused by:
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.eq.else(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.eq.else(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.eq.aY(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.C(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ae.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ae.if(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.if(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.bi.C(Unknown Source)
        at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.c.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.b.v.if(Unknown Source)
        at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.request(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.x.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.q.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.do(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.if(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ClientDocument.open(Unknown Source)
        at com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.ReportClientDocument.open(Unknown Source)
        at com.cbnco.idsys.common.reports.soap.ReportsServlet.doPost(ReportsServlet.java:183)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:283)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:767)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:697)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:889)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this report does not have any formulas using division.  Nor does it include any formulas specifically using the old database field I removed.  No percentages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's in an if/else statement - possibly conditional formatting?  Those will be buried in the objects.  Really though, there's not enough info here to help you, but you tell 'em.  You tell the world.

When I used to do crystal reports, I would screw up the report often. I would figure out what I had to do to get it working, then revert the report back to the original. Then I would make only the small changes I needed to make very carefully. You may find this approach helps.